# Automatic removing of danging images and supporting cache at same time for multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to set up a CI build that builds an image from Dockerfile that contains a multi-step configuration.

### Here are the requirements:

1. It is required to use Docker layers cache because it loads a lot of app dependencies during `RUN` instruction.
2. It should automatically remove old dangling images after each build. (To prevent cleaning it manually in future `docker image prune`)

### My sample solution:

(just to demonstrate the issue) looks like this:

```sh
docker build -t sample-app.
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY some-file-for-build.txt /app
RUN echo 'building...'

FROM ubuntu:18.04
CMD ["echo", "running..."]
```

### The issue:

Because of removing dangling images the cache becomes invalid and `RUN` instruction is performed during each build.

### Unexpected behavior with single-stage config

But if remove 2nd step, so change Dockerfile to this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /app
COPY some-file-for-build.txt /app
RUN echo 'building...'
```

The cache becomes working for the `RUN` instruction.

```
Step 4/4 : RUN echo 'building...'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c7c15230600
```

### Questions:

- Is there any way to make it work according to the requirements?
- Why does cache works with the single-stage configuration but doesn't work with the multi-stage one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to be on Docker version 18.09 and above and also need to set an environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`. This environment variable enables usage of the BuildKit feature, which in turn allows higher performance docker builds and caching possibility to decrease build times. You can get further information [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/)
- As far as I have encountered, cache works for both single-stage and multi-stage configuration using `Docker >18.09`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY some-file-for-build.txt /app
RUN echo 'building...'

FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/some-file-for-build.txt some-file-for-build-from-builder-stage.txt
CMD ["bash"]
```

Here are the logs of my docker build and cleanup:

```
> docker build --pull --rm -f "61977760.Dockerfile" -t 61977760:latest "."
[+] Building 4.7s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from 61977760.Dockerfile                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 289B                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                                     2.4s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 44B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:3235326357dfb65f1781dbc4df3b834546d8bf914e82cce58e6e6b676e23ce8f                                       0.3s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:3235326357dfb65f1781dbc4df3b834546d8bf914e82cce58e6e6b676e23ce8f                                               0.0s
 => => sha256:3235326357dfb65f1781dbc4df3b834546d8bf914e82cce58e6e6b676e23ce8f 1.42kB / 1.42kB                                                                      0.0s
 => => sha256:b58746c8a89938b8c9f5b77de3b8cf1fe78210c696ab03a1442e235eea65d84f 1.15kB / 1.15kB                                                                      0.0s
 => => sha256:c3c304cb4f22ceb8a6fcc29a0cd6d3e4383ba9eb9b5fb552f87de7c0ba99edac 3.41kB / 3.41kB                                                                      0.0s
 => [builder 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [builder 3/4] COPY some-file-for-build.txt /app                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [builder 4/4] RUN echo 'building...'                                                                                                                            0.8s
 => [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=builder /app/some-file-for-build.txt some-file-for-build-from-builder-stage.txt                                                       0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                              0.9s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                             0.8s
 => => writing image sha256:94fd1e56c8044f0e2f80ee83c784cca5f2c384fd4eba9210f9ff81db68f406e5                                                                        0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/61977760:latest                                                                                                                  0.0s
> docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)      
Deleted: sha256:4d157078805ccf08fd42502b19a665a0b60e80a33a7c5b6485e6fd201ca91cc1
Deleted: sha256:6f7f45cca948cf855afea76ff73878b8348da6ed2652d62b48f992f7d9768822
Deleted: sha256:eefe65e58b69e4567c5145828ec95d1d9f3477709cc76fb571e204920df8e378
> docker build --pull --rm -f "61977760.Dockerfile" -t 61977760:latest "."
[+] Building 0.9s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from 61977760.Dockerfile                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 47B                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                                     0.8s
 => [builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:3235326357dfb65f1781dbc4df3b834546d8bf914e82cce58e6e6b676e23ce8f                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 42B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/4] COPY some-file-for-build.txt /app                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 4/4] RUN echo 'building...'                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=builder /app/some-file-for-build.txt some-file-for-build-from-builder-stage.txt                                                0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:94fd1e56c8044f0e2f80ee83c784cca5f2c384fd4eba9210f9ff81db68f406e5                                                                        0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/61977760:latest                                                                                                                  0.0s
> docker builder prune --all                                              
WARNING! This will remove all build cache. Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted build cache objects:
np9zknowpkgi9aa2qtfstthnr
l0lucvc40nl98ceqxqadjplaw
elj14uwncgbk928oawwalht9x
s4l0w4h3day53tc3w20njd9cm
t6br3zadzcqhwilswvhkc2qkv
q8wrflxp3sppgmrft0yv805l0
qbe59a3kgjdvaw4ng7d5rasc8
sha256:82751c4dcc36265daceeee0abd938806b591eb66700863186377348c96e8aead
sha256:24b16cac34768092d57cdb429a12de6c9ee870a3724d70098a189ae0ac344c42
sha256:b1daff3b271fede2bec31812c398e28952f792935f608e467271cdfaccab7de2
sha256:b7f7d2967507ba709dbd1dd0426a5b0cdbe1ff936c131f8958c8d0f910eea19e

Total reclaimed space: 64.21MB
>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about BuildKit. It works with it as I wanted.